# Accessing widget information

Tags: plugins, widgets

I'm trying to access widget information saved in the `wp_options` table.
I printed it out:

```
add_filter('the_content', function(){
    $res = get_option('widget_my_widget');
    print_r($res);
});
```

And it outputted this:

```
Array ( [2] => Array ( [title] => asian kung-fu generation [description] => awesome band ) [_multiwidget] => 1 )
```

My question: is the data always stored at index 2? If not, how can I access the data without worrying if it gives me the correct one or not?

Comment: What happens when you have two instances of the widget?

Comment: I tried it, and there's index 2 and then index 3 for the second instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the index value goes incrementing and we add/remove instances of the widget.

To make sure the correct data is grabbed, I can only think of checking inside the widget data itself through some control variable, something like:

```
Array ( 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [title] => asian kung-fu generation 
        [description] => awesome band 
        [var-of-control] => true (or some other convention) 
    ) 
    [_multiwidget] => 1 
)
```

Or even by title. The [following function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6990868/1287812) does this checking:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function(){
    $res = get_option( 'widget_my_widget' );
    $check = check_array_key_value( $res, 'title', 'asian kung-fu generation' );
    print_r( $check );
});

function check_array_key_value( $array, $key, $val ) 
{
    foreach ( $array as $item )
    {       
        if ( isset( $item[$key] ) && $item[$key] == $val)
            return $item;
    }
    return false;
}
```